# R: Generating a data frame to hold an unknown number of elements

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am estimating many linear models with interactions between two factor variables drawn from a large set of factor variables as predictors. Factors may differ in their number of levels and manually counting the number of levels is time-intensive. From these models, I am trying to generate a data frame containing a row for each coefficient estimate of interaction terms only. The coefficient estimates in the lm object are stored in a named vector but I store them in a df.

Currently, I have designed the function to generate a data frame containing these terms for each model. I could do this, save the results, then eventually read in and append/join the data frames but I know this is very slow and inefficient.

Does anyone have an idea for how to calculate the number of interaction terms that will be in the model then store the results in a data frame I've generated to fit the number of results?

Below is a minimal working example where I print the data frames after generating them. I could have saved them as well.

```
# Generate fake data
a <- as.factor(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE))
b <- as.factor(sample(c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), 20, replace = TRUE))
c <- as.factor(sample(0:10, 20, replace = TRUE))
d <- as.factor(sample(0:12, 20, replace = TRUE))
y <- rnorm(20)
df <- data.frame(y,a,b,c,d)

# The factor variable names are:
vars <- c("a","b","c", "d")

# Loop through all the factors
for (i in 1:(length(vars) - 1)){
  for (j in (i+1):length(vars)){

    # Generate the right-hand side of the formula using
    # the fact that (x+y+z)^2 expands in the lm() formula
    # to all main and interaction terms for all two-way
    # interactions: (x + y + z + x:y + x:z + z:y)
    rhs <- c(vars[i], vars[j]) %>% 
      paste(., collapse = "+") %>%
      paste0("(", ., ")", "^2")

    # Generate left-hand side
    lhs <- paste0("y", " ~ ")

    # Generate the model formula
    my_mod <- paste0(lhs, rhs) %>% 
      formula()

    # Fit the model, save coefficients
    mod_sum <- lm(my_mod, data = df)
    mod_coef <- mod_sum$coefficients

    # Identify interaction coefficients by the ":"
    # symbol and keep only the interaction terms in a df
    int_coefs_df <- mod_coef %>% 
      names() %>% 
      grep(":",.) %>%
      mod_coef[.] %>%
      data.frame(estimate = .)

    print(int_coefs_df)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list when you want to accumulate multiple data frames and cannot estimate up-front how many data frames you will be needing. Or if the data frames vary in sizes.

```
results <- list()
k <- 1
for (i in vars) {
  for (j in mars) {
    # do calculations
    newresult <- calculation(i, j)
    if (skipsavingresult)
      next
    results[[k]] <- newresult
    k <- k + 1
  }
}
all_results <- dplyr::bind_rows(results) ## this is where you concatenate
```

You should consider this approach in contrast to the naïve approach of `results <- rbind(results, newresult)` (or similar). In the later example, saving the results will take longer and longer time, as for *each* iteration *all* data in `results` and `newresult` are copied and saved in a new variable. Lists in R are smarter; every time you append a result, it simply adds a kinda pointer from the list at the new index to your variable, i.e. no data copying.

Comment: I don't see any function definitions in your code. Ask a new question with a minimal working example of this behaviour. Best chance is that you cannot reproduce the error, but get the correct behaviour which you then can use in your "production" code.

Comment: My mistake: I forgot I deleted code to make my MWE more minimal! All is good.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed your code and set some seeds to try to produce a reproducible example.

```
set.seed(1)
a <- as.factor(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE))
set.seed(2)
b <- as.factor(sample(c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), 20, replace = TRUE))
set.seed(3)
c <- as.factor(sample(0:10, 20, replace = TRUE))
set.seed(4)
d <- as.factor(sample(0:12, 20, replace = TRUE))
set.seed(5)
y <- rnorm(20)
df <- data.frame(y,a,b,c,d)
```

In order to calculate the total number of interactions, you can run the following code:

```
Levels <- c(length(levels(a)), length(levels(b)),
            length(levels(c)), length(levels(d)))
TempLevels <- Levels - 1
Total <- 0
for(i in 1:length(Levels) - 1){
  Total <- Total + TempLevels[1] * sum(TempLevels[-1])
  TempLevels <- TempLevels[-1]
}
```

Should return 177 different interactions. You can then use this to create the data.frame for you to store the values. Not sure how fast this will be though.

Comment: I think it returns 151

Comment: Not sure what you're looping for here. You're indexing by i but there is no i in the loop.

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini My bad. Probably due to me using R 3.6. I tried using R 3.5, and it returned 151.

Comment: @user3614648 In this case, the object "Levels" has a length of 4, and I want to loop it 3 times. But the problem is that during each iteration, I want to refer to the first element, since I am removing the first element after each iteration.